# Improve Advanced Filter processing time

Tags: vba, excel

The code below loops through records and returns certain values off of an advanced filter/calculation for each record. I have about 2,000 records I need it to run through. The problem is the processing time is 10-15 seconds a record, which is too slow.

```
Sub EquityAutomatedDallas()
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim LogNo As String

Dim LogNoRange As Range
Dim NoRange As Range
Dim FilterRange As Range
Dim FilterCriteriaRange As Range
Dim ValueRange As Range
Dim FullSortRange As Range
Dim SortValueRange As Range
Dim FullSortRangeValues

Dim EquityRankRange As Range
Dim EquityOutOfRange As Range
Dim MedianRange As Range
Dim PropertyValueRange As Range
Dim DifferenceRange As Range
Dim MinRange As Range
Dim MaxRange As Range
Dim AverageRange As Range
Dim DallasRes As Worksheet

Set LogNoRange = Worksheets("EquitySpreadsheet").Range("B10")
Set NoRange = Worksheets("Dallas Res").Range("A10:A647649")
Set FilterRange = Worksheets("Dallas Res").Range("A9:T647649")
Set FilterCriteriaRange = Worksheets("Dallas Res").Range("A1:T2")
Set ValueRange = Worksheets("Dallas Res").Range("T10:T647649")
Set FullSortRange = Worksheets("Dallas Res").Range("A9:S647649")
Set SortValueRange = Worksheets("Dallas Res").Range("T9")
Set FullSortRangeValues = Worksheets("Dallas Res").Range("A10:T647649")
Set DallasRes = Worksheets("Dallas Res")

Set EquityRankRange = Worksheets("EquityList").Range("P5")
Set EquityOutOfRange = Worksheets("EquityList").Range("P4")
Set MedianRange = Worksheets("EquityList").Range("O6")
Set PropertyValueRange = Worksheets("EquityList").Range("D5")
Set DifferenceRange = Worksheets("EquityList").Range("O7")
Set MinRange = Worksheets("EquityList").Range("O8")
Set MaxRange = Worksheets("EquityList").Range("O9")
Set AverageRange = Worksheets("EquityList").Range("O10")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False



For Counter = 558 To 565
LogNo = Worksheets("Hirschy").Cells(1 + Counter, 1).Value
LogNoRange = LogNo
    NoRange.ClearContents
    Application.Calculate
        If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
            DoEvents
        End If
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    FilterRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=FilterCriteriaRange, Unique:=False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    NoRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=Subtotal(3,R10C2:RC[1])"
    ValueRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = "=INDEX(EquitySpreadsheet!$C$12:$GT$29,16,(MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1)),EquitySpreadsheet!$C$12:$GS$12)+1))"
    DallasRes.Select
    FullSortRange.Select
    SortValueRange.Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dallas Res").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dallas Res").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ValueRange, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dallas Res").Sort
        .SetRange FullSortRangeValues
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
Worksheets("Dallas Res").Calculate
Worksheets("EquitySpreadsheet").Calculate
Worksheets("EquityList").Calculate
Worksheets("Hirschy").Cells(1 + Counter, 6) = EquityRankRange
Worksheets("Hirschy").Cells(1 + Counter, 7) = EquityOutOfRange
Worksheets("Hirschy").Cells(1 + Counter, 8) = MedianRange
Worksheets("Hirschy").Cells(1 + Counter, 9) = PropertyValueRange
Worksheets("Hirschy").Cells(1 + Counter, 10) = DifferenceRange
Worksheets("Hirschy").Cells(1 + Counter, 11) = MinRange
Worksheets("Hirschy").Cells(1 + Counter, 12) = MaxRange
Worksheets("Hirschy").Cells(1 + Counter, 13) = AverageRange
Next Counter
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Is there anyway I can speed up this macro?

Comment: Anyway you can post the workbook? With this kind of problem it's really tough without it in front of you.

Comment: If you don't need to **see** the changes made on each iteration, move the  `ScreenUpdating` outside the loop. Avoid `.Select`, `.Activate`. Use appropriate variable to access the worksheets and ranges, and use `With...End With` on code that access the same object multiple times. Also use Named Ranges if possible.

Comment: I took your advice and cleaned up the code. See above for the updated code. Is there anything else I can do? It is still taking about 10 seconds per record. Excel Hero, unfortunately I cannot as it is too large. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: I see you're switching the calculation mode to manual and back to automatic WITHIN the loop. Not great, cause you're forcing a recalculation of all the cells every time you iterate over one row. Try and move this outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in comments, turning calculations on and off inside the loop is probably not needed, unless you have other calculations depending on the updated values

Your code cleanup helped and I cleaned it up a bit more, but the main change that might affect performance is removing the switching of calculation outside the loop

This is untested so make sure you end up with the expected values; if it works it might make it faster

```
Sub EquityAutomatedDallas()
    Dim i As Long, LogNoRng As Range
    Dim wsHi As Worksheet:          Set wsHi = Worksheets("Hirschy")
    Dim wsES As Worksheet:          Set wsES = Worksheets("EquitySpreadsheet")
    Dim wsEL As Worksheet:          Set wsEL = Worksheets("EquityList")
    Dim wsDa As Worksheet:          Set wsDa = Worksheets("Dallas Res")
    Dim subTotalsDa As Range:       Set subTotalsDa = wsDa.Range("A10:A647649")
    Dim fltrRng As Range:           Set fltrRng = wsDa.Range("A9:T647649")
    Dim fltrCritRng As Range:       Set fltrCritRng = wsDa.Range("A1:T2")
    Dim valRngDa As Range:          Set valRngDa = wsDa.Range("T10:T647649")
    Dim fullSrtRng As Range:        Set fullSrtRng = wsDa.Range("A9:S647649")
    Dim sortValRng As Range:        Set sortValRng = wsDa.Range("T9")
    Dim fullSortRngVal As Range:    Set fullSortRngVal = wsDa.Range("A10:T647649")
    Dim equityRankRng As Range:     Set equityRankRng = wsEL.Range("P5")
    Dim equityOutOfRng As Range:    Set equityOutOfRng = wsEL.Range("P4")
    Dim medianRng As Range:         Set medianRng = wsEL.Range("O6")
    Dim propValRng As Range:        Set propValRng = wsEL.Range("D5")
    Dim diffRng As Range:           Set diffRng = wsEL.Range("O7")
    Dim minRng As Range:            Set minRng = wsEL.Range("O8")
    Dim maxRng As Range:            Set maxRng = wsEL.Range("O9")
    Dim avgRng As Range:            Set avgRng = wsEL.Range("O10")

    xlEnableWB False    'Turns OFF everything, including automatic calculations
    For i = 558 To 565
        LogNoRng = wsHi.Cells(1 + i, 1).Value2
        subTotalsDa.ClearContents
        fltrRng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
            CriteriaRange:=fltrCritRng, Unique:=False
        subTotalsDa.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=Subtotal(3,R10C2:RC[1])"
        valRngDa.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = _
            "=INDEX(EquitySpreadsheet!$C$12:$GT$29,16,(MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1)),EquitySpreadsheet!$C$12:$GS$12)+1))"
        With wsDa.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=valRngDa, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRng fullSortRngVal
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .Apply
        End With
        With wsHi
            .Cells(1 + i, 6) = equityRankRng:   .Cells(1 + i, 7) = equityOutOfRng
            .Cells(1 + i, 8) = medianRng:       .Cells(1 + i, 9) = propValRng
            .Cells(1 + i, 10) = diffRng:        .Cells(1 + i, 11) = minRng
            .Cells(1 + i, 12) = maxRng:         .Cells(1 + i, 13) = avgRng
        End With
    Next
    Application.Calculate
    xlEnableWB True     'Turns ON everything, including automatic calculations
End Sub
```

---

Functions to turn on and off Excel features (screen, Calculations, etc)

```
Public Sub xlEnableWB(Optional ByVal opt As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .Calculation = IIf(opt, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
        .DisplayAlerts = opt
        .DisplayStatusBar = opt
        .EnableAnimations = opt
        .EnableEvents = opt
        .ScreenUpdating = opt
    End With
    xlEnableWS , opt
End Sub
Public Sub xlEnableWS(Optional ws As Worksheet = Nothing, Optional opt As Boolean = True)
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        For Each ws In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets:   EnableWS ws, opt:   Next
    Else
        EnableWS ws, opt
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub EnableWS(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal opt As Boolean)
    With ws
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False
        .EnableCalculation = opt
        .EnableFormatConditionsCalculation = opt
        .EnablePivotTable = opt
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I will incorporate these changes. However, I can't turn off calculation as the values are pulled off a grid that recalculates based on the returned results.

Comment: Calculations are turned off during execution only; they get turned back on, and the entire sheet recalculated in the last 2 lines, at the end

Comment: It returns the same value into the cells value over and over with that code. I think it is because I need the formulas in the workbook to run (calculate) each time through the loop. Is there an alternative if I need the workbook to refresh with each time through the loop? I appreciate your help.

Comment: I see... If I could recreate a small test environment to replicate your functionality exactly, except with 10 rows and 10 columns, there might be a other ways to get it working the same way. Calculations can be very expensive as they trigger all dependencies through ought the workbook(s) and worksheets; see this Microsoft link on ["Tips for Optimizing Performance"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff726673(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I am going to take this as a great solution. It is a large improvement over the 5 minutes it was taking before. 15 seconds by 5,000 records is manageable, since I only have to do it once a year.

Comment: If it works and it does the proper calculations, the improvement is quite significant